# Pass method as parameter for another method

Tags: java, oop, object, methods

I want to do something like this:

```
public class Myclass() {
ArrayList<Object> objects;

public Myclass() {
    this.objects = new ArrayList<>();
}
public ArrayList<Object> callObjectAndMethod(Method method, String string) {
    ArrayList<Object> returnlist = new ArrayList<>();
    // call method for given object reference. I also assume that return value of the method is String
    String output = object.method();
    for (Object object : this.objects) {
       if (object.method.contains(string)) {
           returnlist.add(object.method());
       }
    return returnlist; 
    }

}
```

Is it possible to pass method as parameter for another method ? Also i would like to do this sort of iteration for multiple variable types. int,String,double is there way to create method that works with multiple input types. (probably not) but i am only trying to reduce the amount of lines i have to write. i will have a lot to write if i write this thing for all the methods i want to compare or use copy-paste technique and change little things (which is not good).

Comment: Maybe you should take a step back and describe what you actually want to achieve with this.

Comment: @adder reduce the amount of lines i have to write ?

Comment: Well this line contains two bugs: `String output = object.method();` You don't use `output` and `object` is not defined.

Comment: I find it very generalized question though I preferred answering. You should think in functional way now with java 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use java-8 functional Programming. It allows using `Function Interfaces` to create such implementations called `lambda expressions`. These lambda expressions could be passed as variables to other methods. For example

> Predicate isLengthTen = string -> string.length() == 10;

Now this could be passed as a parameter to any method. Hence, you could use java 8 functional programming easily to pass the code as parameter basically.

```
boolean testTruth(Predicate<T> predicate,T dataUnderTest){
     predicate.test(dataUnderTest);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Quick read about how to use  is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functional-interfaces-java/)